# How to trigger a new ._read in Readable if the previous one returned without pushing data?

Tags: node.js, stream

I am trying to write a Readable which fuses a variable number of input streams (audio buffers). Sometimes, there are no inputs to fuse (because nothing has been registered, because they are lagging behind...). In these situations, my `Readable._read` has nothing to push to the buffer, and it just returns.

**My problem :** When `._read` returns without pushing new data, subsequent calls to `.read` also return `null` without even calling `._read`. How do I re-enable internal calls to `._read` ?

I'm using Node v20.5.1

Here is a minimal example showing this effect. The `Mixer` class allows registering various streams in its `inputs` attribute. In `_read`, I gather data from all of the registered input streams and concatenate. If no input has been registered, I just return without pushing to the buffer.

```js
const { Readable } = require('stream');

class DummyInput extends Readable {
    constructor(letter, options) {
        super(options);
        this.letter = letter;
    }
    _read(_size) {
        this.push(this.letter);
    }
}

class Mixer extends Readable {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
        this.inputs = [];
    }
    add(input) {
        this.inputs.push(input);
    }
    hasData() {
        return this.inputs.length > 0;
    }
    _read(_size) {
        console.log("[reading]")
        const all_letters = this.inputs.map((i) => (i.read(1)))
        if (all_letters.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.push(all_letters.join(''));
    }
}

const options = { highWaterMark: 5, objectMode: true };
const mixer = new Mixer(options);
const dummyA = new DummyInput("A", options);

console.log(mixer.read());
mixer.add(dummyA);
console.log(mixer.read());
```

What I expected, maybe with some additional logs of `[reading]` due to the buffering.

```
[reading]
null
[reading]
A
```

But in practice, `._read` is executed only the first time, and the buffer stays empty for the following calls.

```
[reading]
null
null
```

Reading the source code of Node streams, it looks like calls to `._read` are scheduled at the end of `.push`. But it looks like it should still be called by `.read`, and I don't understand why it is not.